# Getting Buttons to Disappear and Reapper

Tags: iphone, ios, animation, gesture

I have an app where i have an IBAction which recognizes a tap gesture and i want the tap to make the buttons on screen disappear then reappear once tapped.

```
- (IBAction)showFullScreen:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender {








}
```

I know its probably an animation. I have 4 buttons and the UIImageView is what I need to just appear by itself

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
-(void)showButton {
self.button.hidden = NO;
}


-(IBAction) hidebutton{    
[self performSelector:@selector(showButton) withObject:nil
afterDelay:1.5];}
```

Answer (score 4):

You mean you want them to run two animations in a row? Try:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1 animations:^{
    view1.layer.opacity = 0;
    view2.layer.opacity = 0;
} completion:^(BOOL finished){
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1 animations:^{
        view1.layer.opacity = 1;
        view2.layer.opactiy = 1;
    }];
}];
```

You will need to include coregraphics to access the layer property.

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

Your other option is to use a key frame animation with [CAKeyframeAnimation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CAKeyframeAnimation_class/Introduction/Introduction.html)

Comment: I want the user to be able to tap again after the buttons go away to have them reappear. similar to the photos app

Answer (score 1):

to hide 
mybutton.hidden=YES;
to show
mybutton.hidden=NO;

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like you have two steps: first tap makes buttons dissapear and an image appear, seocnd tap reverses it.  Since alpha values are floats, and floats aren't very reliable about having exact values that you can use == to compare with, I tend to prefer to use an external bool property to track that kind of thing.  (I haven't actually seen very many issues with using it for alphas, so feel free to just check the alpha variables instead)

```
if(buttonsShowing)//(button1.view.opacity==1)
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1 animations:^{
        button1.view.opacity = 0;
        button2.view.opacity = 0;
        button3.view.opacity = 0;
        imageView.opacity = 1;
    }];
}
}
else
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1 animations:^{
        button1.view.opacity = 1;
        button2.view.opacity = 1;
        button3.view.opacity = 1;
        imageView.opacity = 0;
    }];
}
buttonsShowing=!buttonsShowing;
```

Comment: Updated text -- I meant alpha

Comment: I'm pretty new to Dev. So the code you provided will do the actions I need them to if I just copy the code and stick in in the method for the tap gesture and rename the buttons to the names I assigned them

Comment: Is that a question or a statement?  :D  I'm making large assumptions about what you're trying to do and your overall structure.  Since 9/10ths or more of what IB provides is based on views, almost object can, if linked to, be given an opacity value -- UIButtons, UILabels, UIImageViews, etc etc.  If you're looking to swap having buttons and images, this should work.

Comment: I want a tap gesture to make my buttons disappear and then once it's tapped again the buttons come back. Kinda like when you tap a photo in the photos app. I think the code you provided should work

Comment: Well, feel free to accept it.  You'll want to kill the references to image view opacity, but otherwise, yes, it sounds like this will do what you want.